# Can i reset session_id before login in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, session, session-cookies

I am trying to reset session_Id before login, and after resetting I am assigning the values to session. This value is not going to new session id. Please help in this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        Session.Abandon();
        Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
        Session["name"] = "athil";
        Response.Redirect("webform1.aspx");

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Button1_Click()` event contains the value "Athil" in `Session["name"]`. This is because the Session object is not destroyed until the server has finished processing.

When you redirect and access the `Session["name"]` on a subsequent Web page, it is empty. This is because `Session["name"]` is destroyed with the previous Session object when the page  finished processing.

New Session object is created when you open a subsequent Web page, after abandoning a session. You can store variables and objects in this new Session object.

Comment: Yes brother, Its working I pass the value to next page through Params and assign the value to session, Then redirect to the previous page. Simple logic. Thanks a lot.